# Как отправлять изображения, хранящиеся локально, в telegram боте?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, файлы, telegram

Есть метод, отправляющий юзеру картинку. Если в параметр photo вставить ссылку на изображение в интернете, то всё работает. Но если прописываю путь к изображению, хранящемуся на компьютере - ничего не выходит. Читал гайд по библиотеке Telegram.Bot, но там не написано как отправлять изображения, которые хранятся локально.

```
if (message.Text.ToLower() == "пикча")
{
    await botClient.SendPhotoAsync(
        chatId: message.Chat.Id,
        photo: "/Users/josephbreat/Projects/PonememiBot/PonememiBot/321.jpg"
    );
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так это делается

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead("/Users/josephbreat/Projects/PonememiBot/PonememiBot/321.jpg"))
{
    await botClient.SendPhotoAsync(
        chatId: message.Chat.Id,
        photo: fs,
        caption: "название картинки"
    );
}
```